# Is $\mathcal{L}^p \subset \mathcal{L}^{p-1} $?

Tags: probability-theory, vector-spaces, random-variables

A random variable $X$ is called integrable if $E[X] < \infty$.

We say that $X \in \mathcal{L}^1$ if $E[X] < \infty$, and in general $X \in \mathcal{L}^p$ if $E[|X|^p] < \infty$.

I know that $\mathcal{L}^1, \mathcal{L}^2$ are vector spaces, plus $\mathcal{L}^2 \subset \mathcal{L}^1$.

Is this true in general?

Is $\mathcal{L}^p$ always a vector space and $\mathcal{L}^p \subset \mathcal{L}^{p-1} $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and you may verify that by using [Holder's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) (check the section on Probability Measures). That those spaces are vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ should be pretty clear, but they are also normed spaces (once you work with equivalence classes, of course) with the norm in $\mathcal{L}^p$ given by $||f||_p=(\int_{\Omega} |f|^p d\mu)^{\frac{1}{p}}=E[|f|^p]^{\frac{1}{p}}$. The triangle inequality here is [Minkowski's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Comment: clear! Thank you very much! ;-)